# Change text of submit button after form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, submit

I have an email signup form, and want the submit button to change from 'submit' to 'thanks' when form is sent. Been digging and haven't been able to find a solution.

```
 <form id="signup" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
      <fieldset>

            <span id="response">
                <? require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>
              </span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your e-mail address" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn" alt="submit" />

          <div id="no-spam"><!--We'll never spam or give this address away--></div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I'm using MailChimp's simple subscribe here: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/downloads/mcapi-simple-subscribe-jquery.zip

thanks for your help!!

Comment: How do you know the form is submited or not? YOu done form submission using php or jquery

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shorthand if statement to change the result, you don't need JavaScript to do it. Unless that is what you need?

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?=($_GET['submit'])? "Thanks" : "Submit"?>" class="btn" alt="submit" />
```

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work. Perhaps the ajaxy response text is messing with stuff? See here: [http://the-contrary.com/](http://the-contrary.com/)

Comment: Have you tried `$_REQUEST['submit']` instead of `$_GET['submit']`?

Answer (score 1):

First, add an `onsubmit` attribute.

```
<form id="signup" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get" onsubmit="sayThanks()">
```

Add an `id` to the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitButton" value="submit" class="btn" alt="submit" />
```

Finally, declare the `sayThanks()` function:

```
function sayThanks(){
    document.getElementById("submitButton").value = "Thanks!";
}
```

Comment: Hi @proulxsie if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#signup").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            $("input[type='submit']").val("Thanks");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails     
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

$("#signup").submit();
```